# cvNet.forward() error (-215:Assertion failed) inputs.size() == requiredOutputs in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::DataLayer::getMemoryShapes

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv

### Problem

We are using Tensorflow in my compagny to generate object detection models. I am personnaly no aware of how TF work : I only get `.pb` and `.pbtxt` files that our machine learning ingeneer has produced. However I would like to visualize the result on a given image using those TF outputs (printing bounding boxes etc.).

I cannot run the `cv.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(pb_file, pbtxt_file)` command in my code in order to apply the model on my image. The complete error is :

`cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-h4wtvo23\opencv\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp:784: error: (-215:Assertion failed) inputs.size() == requiredOutputs in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::DataLayer::getMemoryShapes '`

I have read several posts, but never find something that solves my issue...

### The python script

This script comes from [that tutorial](https://www.programmersought.com/article/68135039272/) :

```
import cv2 as cv
import os

# Load a model imported from Tensorflow
pb_file = 'C/.../model.pb'
pbtxt_file = pb_file[0:-2]+'pbtxt'
img_file = 'C/.../.png' # also tried jpg but did not work

cvNet = cv.dnn.readNetFromTensorflow(pb_file, pbtxt_file)

img = cv.imread(img_file)
rows = img.shape[0]
cols = img.shape[1]
cvNet.setInput(cv.dnn.blobFromImage(img, size=(300, 300), swapRB=True, crop=False))
cvOut = cvNet.forward() # <---------- location of error

for detection in cvOut[0,0,:,:]:
    score = float(detection[2])
    if score > 0.3:
        left = detection[3] * cols
        top = detection[4] * rows
        right = detection[5] * cols
        bottom = detection[6] * rows
        cv.rectangle(img, (int(left), int(top)), (int(right), int(bottom)), (23, 230, 210), thickness=2)

cv.imshow('img', img)
cv.waitKey()
```

The model used is an Inceptionv2.

### Informations

- Python 3.9
- cv2 4.4.0
- Win10

Running the above code step by step returns this error when renning the `cvNet.forward() function` :

```
[ERROR:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-h4wtvo23\opencv\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp (3444) cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::Net::Impl::getLayerShapesRecursively OPENCV/DNN: []:(_input): getMemoryShapes() throws exception. inputs=1 outputs=0/0 blobs=0
[ERROR:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-h4wtvo23\opencv\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp (3447) cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::Net::Impl::getLayerShapesRecursively     input[0] = [ 1 3 300 300 ]

[ERROR:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-h4wtvo23\opencv\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp (3457) cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::Net::Impl::getLayerShapesRecursively Exception message: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-h4wtvo23\opencv\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp:784: error: (-215:Assertion failed) inputs.size() 
== requiredOutputs in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::DataLayer::getMemoryShapes'

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.4.0) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-h4wtvo23\opencv\modules\dnn\src\dnn.cpp:784: error: (-215:Assertion failed) inputs.size() == requiredOutputs in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20200609::DataLayer::getMemoryShapes'
```

Comment: Hi, I am also facing the same bug. I looked up the OpenCV docs but could not find a good reference to start debugging. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hello! Still don't manage to make it work. I used tensorflow directly instead.